# What Code Editor Does Codecademy Use?

Tags: editor, text-editor

I've been doing some courses on the Codecademy website and I found their code editor very useful.

Does anyone know what their code editor is called so I can download it and use it?

Comment: anyone have any ideas???

Comment: This should do the trick for you. On Chrome, right-click on the editor's area, select "Inspect Element", and see what is in the class name of that HTML element. The class name usually implies the text editor that website is using.

Answer (score 11):

It's [Ace Editor](http://ace.c9.io/). You can use it by embedding your webpage. It's [open source](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/).

Answer (score 4):

<s>You can't download it.</s> Woo-hoo! It's a new editor now. Now you can!

However, *Aptana* and *Eclipse* are both nice IDEs you can download and run off-line for web development.  If you're online, [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) are both cool in-browser IDEs to check out.

Answer (score 0):

Code Academy uses the "Tomorrow Dark" Theme. You can get it for various text editors including Notepad++ and Sublimetext here:

https://github.com/ChrisKempson/Tomorrow-Theme

Answer (score -1):

It's called **Labs**, and can be found at [labs.codecademy.com](http://labs.codecademy.com)